# Windows Azure MVC 2 in Dev blank

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I been trying to create a new MVC 2 application under Azure, but when testing it in the Dev Fabric I get nothing but a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this is an IIS configuration issue... I'd look for "static content" and "HTTP redirection" being enabled in IIS.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573369.aspx for a longer list of IIS features to make sure are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I got bitten by this too.  There's a more discriptive thread on the msdn forums about this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/0dbecc0b-d5a9-4bf7-a528-23ab793cf3ef