# Can not find any routes when creating an mvc2 site in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, azure, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am building an mvc 2 web site in windows azure.  It seems to work fine as an mvc 2 site on the dev server, but when I run it in azure's dev fabric, I run into an issue where I can see the web site.  When I launch from the debugger, IE brings up 127.0.0.1:81 as a blank page.  I can't seem to find any of my routes.  Here is what I have tried so far

- setting System.Web.* assemblies to Copy Local = true
- http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx
- set a .html page at the root.  This I can actually see

Here is what my route looks like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{word}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Definition", action = "Index", word = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
            );
            RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

Any suggestions on how I can better debug this?

Answer (score 0):

This is answered here:
[Windows Azure MVC 2 in Dev blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424523/windows-azure-mvc-2-in-dev-blank/5190235#5190235)